# Core Data: How to Retrieve Entities with a Specific Attribute Value?

Tags: ios, core-data

In my iOS app, I'm using Core Data to get entities with a specified property value. Assume I have a "Person" object with attributes "name" (String) and "age" (Integer). How can I use Core Data in Swift to get all "Person" entities with the "age" property equal to 25?

Any assistance or code snippets would be highly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `NSPredicate`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506638-predicate

Answer (score 2):

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
// Use NSPredicate like bellow
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "age == %@", "25")
do {
    let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
        print(result.valueForKey("name") as! String)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```

Comment: Note that in a more "precise app", if we have the classes, you could use NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person"), avoiding you to do `as! [NSManagedObject]`, but `results` would already be a `[Person]`, and you could use `result.name` directly. Also, then you could use `NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", argumentArray: [#keyPath(Person.age), 25"])` (avoiding hard coded string values).